# Code works on one computer - but not on others

Tags: sql-server, ms-access-2007

I have a table called CustItemExp and a table called SetupExp (only one record, 2 fields, Droppath = C:\ECM, LocationName = Test). I'm transferring the CustItemExp to a csv file and calling 1 fields in SetupExp to add the name + date.csv.

The problem is it only works on 1 computer. I need to be able to package and use on other computers

When I run it on another computer I get;
Run-time error '3625'
The text file specification 'CustItemExp' does not exist. You cannot import, export, or link using the specification.

I can see the table CustItemExp in the database!

```
DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, , "CustItemExp", _
Trim(DFirst("droppath", "dbo_SetupExp")) & _
Trim(DFirst("LocationName", "dbo_SetupExp")) & _
Format(Now, "yymmdd HH:MM:SS") & ".csv", True
```

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. CustItemExp does not exist.

Comment: It does exist, maybe the access can't see it? It's in the database and I can see it and edit it.

Comment: Note that it specifies "The **text file specification** 'CustItemExp' does not exist"

Comment: So the table I see does not exist?

Answer (score 0):

This is complaining that your file specification for the export does not exist in the database. This is parameter 2 on the DoCmd.TransferText command. As noted by [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.docmd.transfertext):

> SpecificationName
>
> Optional
>
> Variant
>
> A string expression that's the name of an import or export specification you've created and **saved in the current database.** For a fixed-width text file, you must either specify an argument or use a schema.ini file, which must be stored in the same folder as the imported, linked, or exported text file.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, this works on 1 computer but not another. The table is not  "Fixed Width " since it contains several fields that vary in length

Comment: Can you show your entire command? (Fake paths and filenames are fine)

Comment: DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, , "CustItemExp", _
Trim(DFirst("droppath", "dbo_SetupExp")) & _
Trim(DFirst("LocationName", "dbo_SetupExp")) & _
Format(Now, "yymmdd HH:MM:SS") & ".csv", True

Answer (score 0):

I solved it! I made a packaged solution and it now works on any computer